# Issue while trying to install spring-tool-suite-4-4.15.0

Tags: java, spring

Hi I am trying to install spring-tool-suite-4-4.15.0 on a windows 10 machine by executing below command in my CMD

Spring source jar file I download from https://spring.io/tools by clicking on 4.15.0-WINDOWS X84_64

java -jar C:\Workdir\spring-tool-suite-4-4.15.0.RELEASE-e4.24.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar

I can see decompress is starting but towards the end I get below exception & process stop incomplete

sts-4.15.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls_1.34.0.202206140708/servers/spring-boot-language-server/META-INF/third-party-open-source-licenses/bsd 3-clause "new" or "revised" license (bsd-3-clause) - apl-v10.html

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\jdk1.8.33\bin\sts-4.15.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls_1.34.0.202206140708\servers\spring-boot-language-server\META-INF\third-party-open-source-licenses\bsd 3-clause "new" or "revised" license (bsd-3-clause) - apl-v10.html (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

```
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)

    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)

    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)

    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)

    at SelfExtractor.unpack(SelfExtractor.java:147)

    at SelfExtractor.run(SelfExtractor.java:47)

    at SelfExtractor.main(SelfExtractor.java:31)
```

My jdk version is as below , any one know where is the issues & how to fix it?

C:\jdk1.8.33\bin>java -version

java version "1.8.0_331"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_331-b25)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.331-b25, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

They are working on it :  https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/788

Please [download the latest snapshot](https://download.springsource.com/snapshot/STS4/nightly/dist/e4.24/spring-tool-suite-4-4.15.1.CI-B2725-e4.24.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar) if you can't wait for the release