# Downloading Spring tool suite for windows 10

Tags: download, ide, sts

[not able to download spring tool suite.It showing spring-boot-language-server META-INFithd-party-open-source-licensesibsd 3-clause "new" or "revised license (bsd-3-clause)-api-v10.html (The filename, directory name, or volume label is incrat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuRLd.png)

Answer (score 0):

They are working on it :  https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/788

Please [download the latest snapshot](https://download.springsource.com/snapshot/STS4/nightly/dist/e4.24/spring-tool-suite-4-4.15.1.CI-B2725-e4.24.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar) if you can't wait for the release

(this question is also a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656059/issue-while-trying-to-install-spring-tool-suite-4-4-15-0/72659023#72659023))